# Merging rows with the same name in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have to prepare charts with R for a case study. I have a dataset containing tens of thousands of rows organized as follows:

```
Platform | Profits

Desktop  |  608.50

Desktop  |  591.54

Desktop  |   83.21

Mobile   |   27.13

Mobile   |  133.81

Mobile   |  201.13
```

There are tens of thousands more Desktop and Mobile rows and their profits than what I posted, but I would like to know if there is a way for me to combine all of the Desktop and Mobile profits so that the resulting table is as follows so I can graph the totals easier:

```
Platform | Profit

Desktop  |5839.01

Mobile   |4219.58
```

I tried subset, sumRows, sumCols, but I can't seem to make a table of this desired format. I am 100% okay with having to break this into parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Platform) %>% 
  summarise(sum_profit = sum(Profits))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Platform sum_profit
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 Desktop       1283.
2 Mobile         362.
```

Data

```
df = structure(list(Platform = c("Desktop", "Desktop", "Desktop", 
"Mobile", "Mobile", "Mobile"), Profits = c(608.5, 591.54, 83.21, 
27.13, 133.81, 201.13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, however the console returns the following error

> platformsValues %>%
+   group_by('Platform Type Name') %>%
+   summarise(sum = sum('Net Gross Booking Value USD'))
Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `sum`.
i `sum = sum("Net Gross Booking Value USD")`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
i The error occurred in group 1: "Platform Type Name" = "Platform Type Name".

Comment: Don't keep space in the variable name e.g. `Platform Type Name` to `PlatformTypeName` or `Platform_Type_Name` and `Net Gross Booking Value USD` to `NetGrossBookingValueUSD` or else you can use shorter column names as you have given in the question.

Comment: I had a feeling the spacing was an issue since I'd have to put it in quotation marks, but that's how it is in the excel sheet, should I just change the excel sheet?

Comment: As in like(platformsValues, 'Net Gross Booking Value USD') ?

Comment: No use backticks.